# Adding CAS to Spring Webapp with GWT results in page not found, but logs in after refresh

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-security, cas

I've tried to debug this without any success. I have a working Spring Application with GWT and Spring Security, but when I change the security-context around to use CAS authentication, I do get redirected to the cas page (usually), but after successful login, I get redirected to the correct url, but I get a "page not found error" at the browser level. After refreshing the page (same url), I'm logged in, and application loads as expected. No errors in the logs, as far as I can tell, no differences in what's happening in the application when using CAS vs normal spring security form login.

Comment: to try to narrow down the problem, i decided to see what would happen if instead of hitting the app url, then be redirected to cas, logging in and then being redirected back to the app, that i would go directly to the cas login without that first redirect. the probelm doesnt happen, so it seems to me the problem must lie in the way that the spring security cas support is maybe holding on the original request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this answered my question:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-cached-secure-page

which basically states that if you're securing html pages, you're in charge of configuring caching, so that a cached page can't be accessed. In my case, this wasn't entirely clear, as the gwt services were still getting secured, so I wasn't seeing secured content, but still, that was the problem-